# Drawer - No Overlay Widget found

Tags: flutter, widget, drawer, appbar, flutter-scaffold

I have a normal `MaterialApp` with `Scaffold` having an `AppBar` and `Drawer`.

**Following Error occurred when building app:**

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Tooltip("Open navigation menu", dirty, state: TooltipState#1bb77(ticker inactive)):
No Overlay widget found.

Tooltip widgets require an Overlay widget ancestor for correct operation.

The most common way to add an Overlay to an application is to include a MaterialApp or Navigator widget in the runApp() call.

The specific widget that failed to find an overlay was: Tooltip
  "Open navigation menu"
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AppBar AppBar:file:///Users/sherzad/Desktop/Programmierung/flutter_projekte/taalamna_projekt/taalamna/lib/my_app.dart:44:21
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

**My Code:**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // final MyAppController controller = Get.put(MyAppController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FirebasePhoneAuthProvider(
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          S.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
        // locale: Locale("ar"), //for testing translation
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        builder: (context, child) {
          // return controller.buildScaffold(child);
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            drawer: Drawer(),
            body: child,
          );
        },
        home:
            // LoginScreen()
            // SplashScreen()
            FlavorConfig.getFlavorName() == FLAVOUR_DEV
                ? const HomeScreen()
                : const SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: Please share the code for the `AppBar`

Comment: It´s standard AppBar from Flutter. No custom AppBar.

Answer (score 1):

As the error stated, you need to wrap your Widget with an Overlay widget

```
builder: (context, child) {
    return Overlay(
      initialEntries: [
        OverlayEntry(
          builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(),
              drawer: Drawer(),
              body: child,
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
```

My understanding on this issue:

According to the [document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp/builder.html)

> A builder for inserting widgets above the Navigator

Your widget expects to have an Overlay, which is added by the Navigator. But since you insert it above the Navigator, now you have to manually add an Overlay

Comment: But why do I need that for a standard scenario?? in the most code available I dont see this overlay widget in use...what did my code make the overlay widget be nessesary?

Comment: @skm I've added my understanding on this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use overlay like this.

```
Overlay(
      initialEntries: [
        OverlayEntry(
          builder: (context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            drawer: Drawer(),
            body: child,
          );
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: But why do I need that for a standard scenario?? in the most code available I dont see this overlay widget in use...what did my code make the overlay widget be nessesary? –